# Playframework - Eclipse can't detect a new template

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Eclipse see the changes in Play! compiled templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042987/how-to-make-eclipse-see-the-changes-in-play-compiled-templates)

I am doing my first steps with the Play! Framework and I run into some problems.
I can create and eclipsify a project without any problems.

Now if I add a new view, for example 'sometest.scala.html' and I try to use it in the 'Application' Eclipse marks this file as an error.

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;


import views.html.*;;

public class Application extends Controller {



public static Result index() {
    return ok(sometest.render("test"));  // this line is marked red
  }

}
```

Eclipse marks sometest red, even if it works. If I go to localhost:9000, I can see my changes.

My view folder looks like this:

```
app
--views
----index.scala.html
----main.scala.html
----sometest.scala.html
```

I created sometest as a html file and set the file name to .scala.html

**Simple solution:**

run your app with

```
$ cd myapp
$ play
$ run
```

go to your webrwoser and type: localhost:9000

create a new .scala.html file in your views folder.

Refresh your website at localhost:9000

Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After creating new view you have to first run the app in the browser, to allow Play to compile it as a Scala class (which are recognized by IDE) then you need to click menu -> Project Build all, then Eclipse will refresh the view.

Optionally you can try IntelliJ which doesn't require any additional actions to start recognizing the freshly created classes.

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but I created a new project and now eclipse automatically refreshes the new scala classes and it works just fine.

Comment: So try to realize :) although I don't need Eclipse support I'm pretty sure that most of people will be interesting about this knowledge, Thanx for info.

Comment: I had the same problem and Build All was disabled. I simply refreshed the project and errors are gone! Right click the project and Refresh.

Answer (score 7):

I run this problem daily while using eclipse, BUT with eclipse this works pretty well already.. run play with play ~run command instead and after that you sometimes only need to select your project in eclipse - right click and refresh, boom = errors gone.