# akka with play framework

Tags: java, playframework, akka

still learning to master akka java with play framework. I have a code snippet below. It was working fine but has decided to give some headaches.

```
public class Application extends Controller {

static ActorRef masterActor;
  RubineActor rubineactor;


  public static Result index() {          
      return ok(index.render(null));
   ........ somecode
  }
```

it was working fine but now my eclipse juno complains that it cannot resolve the index object in the return line . I am new to both akka and play framework . Can someone please explain what is happening to me. cos have to submit the project as my final year project. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to Akka, it's a [template concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739119/playframework-eclipse-cant-detect-a-new-template).

The variable `index` is provided by a template import, certainly `import views.html.*;`
Eclipse sometimes cannot resolve this object because it is generated automatically by Play **after** the first request.

> Templates are compiled as standard Scala functions, following a simple naming convention. If you create a views/Application/index.scala.html template file, it will generate a views.html.Application.index class that has a render() method.

See the [hello word sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/helloworld/app/controllers/Application.java) for a concrete exemple.

Comment: thanks for the explanation will have a look at the sample example.