# After compiling eclipse not showing changes for play framework

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play Framework,and i am doing some RND.
But when i changed class name its corresponding .class name not going to be changed.

i am compiling project in command prompt by

project-path/play compile

Is there any setting to do so.I followed all steps given on www.playframework.org

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Eclipse see the changes in Play! compiled templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042987/how-to-make-eclipse-see-the-changes-in-play-compiled-templates)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here.

You need to changed Default output folder path in eclipse to the path of class_managed folder.

Now after once you compile from command prompt. it will show changes in eclipse.