# Eclipse Juno Reporting Problems With Play Syntax

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

Have installed the Scala plugin < http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-scala-ide-juno-210x > in Eclipse Juno.

Am using the following versions:

play 2.1.0
java version "1.6.0_41"
Scala code runner version 2.10.0 -- Copyright 2002-2012, LAMP/EPFL
I am able to write Scala programs using Eclipse and also created a Java based Play project which I imported into Eclipse by running play eclipse.

Am able to see the sample code run correctly in Chrome but have weird errors regarding the play code.

e.g.

```
public class Application extends Controller {  

   public static Result index() {
       return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
   } 
}
```

There's a red curly line underneath index which the Eclipse problem's view states:

"index cannot be resolved"

Attached is a screenshot giving examples of these type of problems...

Is there a way to have Eclipse recognize these errors?

[image: Play Syntax Problems in Eclipse]

**( You can open this image in a new tab on your browser in order to see it in a larger resolution )**

Comment: tried cleaning project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Eclipse see the changes in Play! compiled templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042987/how-to-make-eclipse-see-the-changes-in-play-compiled-templates)

Comment: "play clean compile" in the Play! console; then try a refresh of the project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I just had EXACTLY this problem with a clean, fresh install of Play (most recent version(s) of everything downloaded on Jan 17th 2015).

I thought to myself -- oh god here we go again -- a wonderful framework when it works but you have to invest 4 hours of mind numbing research just to get the first line of code to compile properly.

Turns out that running the `~compile` command in the `activator` window and making a change in the `Application.java` and saving it did the trick. Changes to the file alone didn't do it nor did running `update` in `activator` either nor restarting or reloading eclipse.

Thank you for asking the question as this is what shows up when googling `return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));` and it looks like I'll be productive now in short order instead of wasting time with the search gods...

I would also give the answerer (Alban) a star but I'm not allowed to yet sadly...

You would think that in 2 years a simple problem like this would have long been fixed long ago!

Answer (score 1):

rather than using;

```
activator eclipse
```

use;

```
activator "eclipse with-source=true"
```

it takes a little while but when it is completed, it doesn't display related error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run compilation from Play! console.

To do it incrementally (*ie* every time you make a change in your source), you can run:

```
play ~compile
```

I also configured Eclipse to automatically refresh resources: Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh using native hooks or polling.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue but Play has a way to set up your project for various ide's. [Try running eclipsify](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/IDE), though eclipse is known to keep dirty caches so that could be one of the issues. If this does not work maybe try running it with the: with-source=true option.