# Scala IDE 4.0.0 thinks there's errors in an out-of-the-box Play Framework 2.3.7 program

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I've created a Play Framework program via Typesafe Activator (so it follows the template exactly).

I used `sbteclipse-plugin` version 3.0.0 to create an Eclipse project and imported that into Scala IDE 4.0.0. These are all the latest versions at the time of writing.

The Scala IDE definitely seems to support the Play Framework. It has syntax highlighting for the custom formats, including the routing file and templates. Yet, it doesn't seem to be able to find the views from the controllers. In particular, the call to `views.html.index` triggers an error: "object index is not a member of package views.html".

[image]

I tried enabling refreshing using native hooks or pooling as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10043634/1968462), but it had no affect.

I should note that while the code has been compiled in the command line (with `activator ~run`), it hasn't been compiled in Scala IDE, since I don't know how to (it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere).

What can I do to get rid of these false errors?

EDIT: After running `activator clean ~run`, I have another error: The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved. There's no further details on what these build path errors are.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same problem. Suspect the plugin does not work with 4.0 scala ide but only 3.x

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update:** Just upgrade to `sbteclipse` version `5.1.0` and everything should work out of the box. Also make sure you follow [the Play documentation on how to set up Eclipse/ScalaIDE](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/IDE#Eclipse).

---

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/issues/229) in `sbteclipse`, which probably [will be fixed](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/pull/242) soon.

For now, you can add the following line to your build.sbt:

```
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.All
```

Kill the SBT console and run `sbt eclipse` again. That should add the following line to the `.classpath` file within your project folder as a workaround:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="target/scala-2.11/twirl/main"/>
```

Refresh your Eclipse project to pick up the change.

Comment: This introduces `Build path contains duplicate entry: 'target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main' for project '...'`. So although it can be manually de-duplicated from the project's java build path in eclipse, this is not really a solution as is. Also I think a project `clean` is necessary not just a refresh, when making these kind of changes. This solution is behaving quite oddly for me.

Comment: After following instructions, refreshing and rebuilding, problem remained.  When I opened project -> java path, several paths, such as twirl/test and .../managed/... still said [empty] after their names.   I had to delete the eclipse project and then re-import it before all java-path entries were present and the view object not found went away.

Comment: @matt, in case you still need it, I found a work-around for that error and posted it as a solution below.

Comment: Thanks! I got used to manually solving it after every `sbt eclipse` but will try if it's not solved in the next release of Play and ScalaIDE

Comment: @pitchblack408 You do not need this workaround anymore for Play 2.4.x. Just follow the guide at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE#Eclipse to set up Eclipse, everything should work out of the box. My workaround here is just for Play 2.3.x.

Comment: Not sure about "will be fixed soon". Amazingly it is still the case that this is not fixed in any release I can see.

Comment: I just updated my answer: Upgrade `sbteclipse` to version `5.1.0` (released yesterday) and everything should work out of the box now (assuming you did follow the set up instruction linked in my answer).

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, also with Scala IDE 4.0.0 . I followed [mkurz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810109/mkurz) instuctions and they worked like a charm. But instead of changing the `.classpath` file in the project folder manually I used Eclipse interface:

- In the top menu of the main window, click on `Project` and then on `Properties`.
- In the `Properties` window, click on `Java Build Path` option (options list is on the left)
- In the `Source` tab, click on `Add Folder...` button.
- In the `Source Folder Selection` window, choose the `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main` folder, so it is included in the compilation path. Click `Ok` button.
- Click `Ok` in the `Properties` window.

Now the project should compile just fine :) . With that I was able to finish [the play setup example in Scala IDE website](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play/)

Comment: Eclipse doesn't see "scala-2.11" folder under target... this is such a joke

Comment: Please see my updated answer: Upgrade `sbteclipse` to version `5.1.0` (released yesterday) and everything should work out of the box now.

Answer (score 4):

I tried @mkurz solution first, but also ran into the same error as @matt. I became frustrated that I could not generate the eclipse project without having to go to the Eclipse project properties to manually fix the build errors. After some investigation, I discovered the solution that removed all errors entirely. Add this your build.sbt:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <+= twirlCompileTemplates.target
```

Or if that does not work for you, you could also use:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <+= target.zipWith(scalaBinaryVersion) { (b,v) => b / s"scala-$v/twirl/main" }
```

Good bye, build errors!

Comment: Same deal for me. It was the 2nd solution listed above that worked for me, the first did not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message.
Are you using java8 as jre in eclipse?
After switching back from java8 to java7, everything worked fine again.

Comment: It was using Java 8 as the JRE, but switching it to Java 7 (and restarting) had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

If, after following Mkurz' instructions (adding EclipseKeys.CreateSrc... ), your problems are not solved, click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path. Look at the source folders tab.

You may find a duplicate file folder named .../src_managed/main (Thanks Matt). If so, close the project. Remove ONE of the two ../src_managed/main entries from the .classpath file (located in the base of the activator/SBT project directory). Reopen and clean the project and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out that installed JRE in the Scala IDE was openjdk, changed it to Oracle Java 8 and it worked.